# How do Google cars recognize the traffic signs?

Tags: deep-learning, image-recognition, classification, autonomous-vehicles, google

The paper [Multi-column Deep Neural Networks for Image Classification](http://repository.supsi.ch/5145/1/IDSIA-04-12.pdf) (pages 7-8) shows an attempt at recognizing the traffic signs, with lower error rates, by using multi-column deep neural networks.

Are Google cars using similar techniques of predicting signs using DNN, or are they using some other method?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what Google is using to perform that task, but most companies use region based convolutional neural nets to locate traffic signs and other objects.

But other companies use a deep neural network + bag of words approach to find objects.

See: [Bag-of-Words Based Deep Neural Network for Image Retrieval](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/284505205_Bag-of-Words_Based_Deep_Neural_Network_for_Image_Retrieval) which shows a general approach, to get the exact location you can use *Feature Matching* or *Random Boxes*.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/284505205_Bag-of-Words_Based_Deep_Neural_Network_for_Image_Retrieval this link shows a general approach, to get the exact  location you can use Feature Matching or Random Boxes